# How to add multiple command insde single if loop in batch scripts

Tags: bash

can you tell me the meaning of this while condition in linux. i have to covert it into bash

i wanted to add multiple commands inside if condition in batch script.
Example
if a file exist
(copy somefile, movesomefile, rename somefile, echo something)
else do something else)

for some reason i am unable to do add multiple commands inside if condions

any help is appreciated

I have tried different commmands in diffrent ways but didn't work.

this is just a sample code which might give you the idea what i am trying to achive

if exist C:\Users\admin\Desktop\TEST\dc.txt (echo "file exist"  timeout /t 10  copy C:\Users\admin\Desktop\TEST\dc.txt C:\Users\admin\Desktop ) else ( echo"hello" copy C:\Users\admin\Desktop\TEST\test.txt C:\Users\admin\Desktop)

Comment: `of this while` - I see no while condition in your post. Which while condition do you have in mind? `Example` - please format your post. You can add two spaces on the end of the line to do a line break.  `insde single if loop` `if` is not a loop, but a condition statement. Please fix your post, use full sentences starting with capital letters ending with full stops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `if` statement is ended with `fi`. You can use `else` and `elif []; then` for else and else-if respectively. Make sure that every command is either on a new line, or separated with a semicolon.

The `[` also has a man page and explains a lot of options you can use with the if statement.

```sh
#! /bin/bash
# usage $0 <filename>

file=$1 # First given argument, in your case "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\TEST\dc.txt"
RET=0

# -f = file exists
if [ -f "$file" ]; then
    # Copy also renames the file
    cp "$file" 'C:\Users\admin\Desktop\some_other_filename.txt'
else
    echo "File does not exist"
    RET=1
fi
exit ${RET}
```

You can omit the double quotes bu using `if [[ -f $file ]]; then`, but I don't use windows and `\` might cause problems since it's used to escape characters (i.e. `\n` for newline).

Furthermore, an if statement can't have an empty body.

Comment: Inside `[[` everything is properly quoted. `\n` will be intepreted as \ followed by `n`.